# Tool-tipping over image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

Wondering how to activate a simple tooltip when hovering over an image. Thought this would be basic enough, but struggling,

HTML

```
<div class = "runners">
    <h1> Hover to see famous runners</h1>
    <img id = "mo-farah" src="Images/mo-farah.jpg" title = "Mo Farah">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  this.tooltip = function() {
    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;
    $("div").hover(function(e) {
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>" + this.t + "</p>");
        $("#tooltip")
          .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
          .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
          .fadeIn("fast");
      },
      function() {
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#tooltip").remove();
      });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    tooltip();
  });
```

I'm not sure where I need to link the image itself in the jQuery.

Apologies for the vagueness, this is the best I could do. Have used Youtube/stack to try and find help, but to no avail.  Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong for you. I've tried it in a jsfiddle and it seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/rdba56x6/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference to jQuery before your reference to jQuery UI.

```js
this.tooltip = function(){            
xOffset = 10;
yOffset = 20;       
$("div").hover(function(e){                             
  this.t = this.title;
  this.title = "";                                    
  $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
  $("#tooltip")
    .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
    .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
    .fadeIn("fast");        
    },
function(){
  this.title = this.t;      
  $("#tooltip").remove();
    });             
  };

$(document).ready(function(){
  tooltip();
});
```

```css
img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add jQuery reference first !-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI reference added after jQuery reference !-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class = "runners">
    <h1> Hover to see famous runners</h1>
    <img id = "mo-farah" src="http://www.mofarah.com/img/bgs/home.jpg" title = "Mo Farah">
    <img id = "usain-bolt" src="http://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/160815202407-usain-bolt-smiles-jeanne-moos-pkg-large-169.jpg" title = "Usain Bolt">
    <img id = "haile-gebreselassie" src="http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/83/285x214/323348_1.jpg" title = "Haile Gebreselassie">
</div>
```